# how to set variable value from aspx.cs file to aspx file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I coded in Image.aspx.cs file as

```
public partial class Necklace : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected int PageId;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PageId = 12;
    }
}
```

AND I coded in Image.aspx file as

```
<div>
<asp:image ToolTip = "ASP Image Control" ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl ="ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=<%= PageId %>" ></asp:image></div>
```

And I coded in ImageCSharp.aspx.cs file as

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Request.QueryString["ImageID"] != null)
        {
            string strQuery = "select ImageName , ImageData from ImageTable where id=@id"; //,Category
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ImageID"]);
            DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["ImageData"];
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                //Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["Category"].ToString();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["ImageName"].ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me how to code  *ImageUrl ="ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=**<%= PageId %>**"* correctly... PageId should be variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it in code behind:

```
protected int PageId;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PageId = 12; // some value 
   Image1.ImageUrl ="ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=" + PageId;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me?
I want to loop Image id as
`for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            **Image1**.ImageUrl = "ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=" + PageId;
        }`

Comment: what do you mean by loop image id? you have a couple of images? are count of them are the same?

Comment: Yes I have 10 images. I can change PageId value. But I don't know hot to use loop to change image id.(Image1.ImageUrl)

Comment: If count of them is static, then you can just set `Image1.ImageUrl = "ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=" + PageID1`, `Image2.ImageUrl = "ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=" + PageID2`, `Image3.ImageUrl = "ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=" + PageID3`, etc. Or if they are dynamic, then you can create them dynamically with `asp:Repeater`

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { 
PageId == i;
Image[i].ImageUrl = "ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=" + PageId; }
I want like this.help me

Comment: Nope. this won't work as you can't iterate controls in such way. But you can do: `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { (MyContainer.FindControl("Image" + i) as Image).ImageUrl = "ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=" + PageId; }`.  MyContainer is control with runat=server that holds all your Images

Comment: How to use MyContainer in this code <asp:image ToolTip = "ASP Image Control" ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl ="ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=<%= PageId %>" ></asp:image>

Comment: MyContainer is an example of control in your aspx that holds all your Images. Like form runat=server, div runat=server, etc. Just server control in which all Images are located

Comment: I can not understand what I use instead MyContainer. please give me an example.