# I want to loop Image id in asp.net aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { (MyContainer.FindControl("Image" + i) as Image).ImageUrl = "ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=" + PageId; }
```

This question related my previous question. so click this link [how to set variable value from aspx.cs file to aspx file in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353499/how-to-set-variable-value-from-aspx-cs-file-to-aspx-file-in-asp-net) and see my previous question.
I can not understand what I use instead MyContainer. please give me an example.

Comment: In simple English, what are you trying to do? I honestly don't understand your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
protected int PageId;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PageId = 12;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
    { 
        Image img = MyContainer.FindControl("Image" + i) as Image;
        img.ImageUrl = "ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=" + PageId; 
    }
}
```

ASPX Layout

```
<div runat="server" id="MyContainer">
    <asp:image ToolTip = "ASP Image Control" ID="Image1" runat="server"></asp:image>
    <asp:image ToolTip = "ASP Image Control" ID="Image2" runat="server"></asp:image>
    <asp:image ToolTip = "ASP Image Control" ID="Image3" runat="server"></asp:image>
    <asp:image ToolTip = "ASP Image Control" ID="Image4" runat="server"></asp:image>
</div>
```

MyContainer is a server container that holds all images.